# Compiling Postgis 2.2.0 on Raspian error doesn't install postgis extension

Tags: postgis, installation, postgis-2.2

Installed postgresql 9.4 following this [tutorial](http://raspberrypg.org/2015/06/step-5-update-installing-postgresql-on-my-raspberry-pi-1-and-2/#section3) using the method of already compiled pkg. All seems fine with postgres installation.

```
testdb=# SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings where category='File Locations';
       name        |                 setting                  
-------------------+------------------------------------------
 config_file       | /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
 data_directory    | /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
 external_pid_file | /var/run/postgresql/9.4-main.pid
 hba_file          | /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf
 ident_file        | /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_ident.conf
(5 rows)
```

Then tried to install postgis 2.2.0 folowing the steps at this trac page (im fairly new with *nix env's and this build from source stuff stills confusing me a lot so go gentle with me) .

1. So downloaded postgis-2.2.0.tar.gz in a /temp_postgis and untarred .
2. List item
   Folowed steps for install from source in this trac for debian whezzy[page](http://So%20downloaded%20postgis-2.2.0.tar.gz%20in%20a%20/temp_postgis%20and%20untarred%20.)
3. During the install it requested many librarys like geos , proj4 and others that i installed.

Now the problem when in try to create postgis extension it gives me an error and i can see the extension at the pgadmin as option to install extension on databases.

receiving the following error:

```
testdb=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
testdb=#
```

Any clues what could have go wrong ? Regards.

EDIT 1: 
After make check -

```
PATH is /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Checking for shp2pgsql ... found
Checking for pgsql2shp ... found
TMPDIR is /tmp/pgis_reg
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
Creating database 'postgis_reg' 
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
Loading PostGIS into 'postgis_reg' 
 failed (Error encountered loading /temp_postgis/postgis-2.2.0/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis/postgis.sql: /tmp/pgis_reg/regress_log)
Makefile:265: recipe for target 'check' failed
make[1]: *** [check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/temp_postgis/postgis-2.2.0/regress'
GNUmakefile:16: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 1
```

Now on the other side- i was able to run the postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql on pgadmin sql window, all ended successfully , i can now see postgis extension as option to install postgis via pgadmin and pslql - recreated a few other db's and installed postgis and seems to be fine . Now the question - if make check tests failed should i worry ? i belleive so :-)

Comment: Not sure why this was voted off-topic.  Anyway if you didn't compile with gdal support, which means you have no raster, then CREATE EXTENSION can't be used.  check in usr/share/contrib/postgis-2.2 and you should find postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql you can use to install

Comment: that's what i was afraid , i have no usr/share/contrib/postgis-2.2 folder , this seems bad

Comment: Did you do make install?  Maybe you compiled but didn't install.

Comment: Dont remember if did , so did it again but still have no contrib dir. At the end of make install received this 2 lines > make[2]: Leaving directory '/temp_postgis/postgis-2.2.0/extensions/postgis_topology'
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/temp_postgis/postgis-2.2.0/extensions'
Expected or something else

Comment: That looks all fine.  BTW meant usr/share/postgresql/9.4/contrib/postgis-2.2 folder.  What does your ./configure statement look like

Comment: Seems to complete with some warnings --- PostGIS is now configured for armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.configure: WARNING:  --------- GEOS VERSION WARNING ------------
configure: WARNING:   You are building against GEOS 3.3.3
configure: WARNING:   To take advantage of all the features of
configure: WARNING:   PostGIS we recommend you build using
configure: WARNING:   GEOS 3.5.0 or higher. You can download
configure: WARNING:   the latest versions from
configure: WARNING:   http://trac.osgeo.org/geos
configure: WARNING:

Comment: did you run make check to see if tests run.  Also what does you configure step output look like?.  The warnings just mean you'll be missing support for some GEOS functions so okay (thought 3.3.3 is pretty old, but that's another story).

Comment: so i run the 'make check' - EDIT 1 :

Comment: and did tests run? Jorge -- might be good to ask tehse questions on postgis users list as I think some peole have raspberry experience installing  postgis.   https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/postgis-users

Comment: yes test did run. I edited the question (EDIT 1) copied the results of the tests , i think they failed. Correct i will list my self on the postgis users list , will probably have more audience. Thanks for all see you soon :-)